# I am using rs/SDWebImage for Asynchronous image loading . But the function is only returning the image on the first call

Tags: ios

I am using rs/SDWebImage for Asynchronous image loading . I am parsing the image url from the json feed and paasing that url to my function . But the function is only returning the image on the first call . When i called it again ... its returning NULL .... How  can i fix this ....

```
   ........
    for (id key1 in tempfileLevel) 
      {
        NSMutableDictionary *tempfileLevel1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        tempfileLevel1 = [tempfileLevel valueForKey:key1];
        NSLog(@" tumbfile name  = %@ " , [tempfileLevel1 valueForKey:@"tumbfile"]);

        NSString *thumbpath = [[NSString alloc] init];
        thumbpath = [tempfileLevel1 valueForKey:@"tumbfile"];
        NSURL *turl = [NSURL URLWithString:thumbpath];

        UIImage *imageDetail;
        imageDetail = [self getimage:turl];
        NSMutableArray *thumbs;
        [thumbs addObject:imageDetail];

     }
   .......
   ......

    - (UIImage*)getImage:(NSURL*)myurl
     {

        SDWebImageManager *manager = [SDWebImageManager sharedManager];
        UIImage *cachedImage = [manager imageWithURL:myurl];
        if (cachedImage)
        {
            // Use the cached image immediatly
        }
        else
        {
            // Start an async download
            [manager downloadWithURL:myurl delegate:self];
        }
        NSLog(@" image we got = %@",cachedImage);
    return cachedImage;

    }
```

What i have to do to fix this .....